# Quorum " now " returns bad number

Tags: solidity, contract-development, quorum

I am using the prebuilt function `now` in my contract and returning it as an `uint`. but when i read it using `web3 1.0` i get bigger numbers than usual :

**Example :**
This what the number should look like from number of digits pov: `1522342012`
this is what i get : `1522339819405493950`

I tried getting this as a solidity `string` or `bytes32` but i still get the same number of digits.

Comment: Please share your code. (A Solidity function that returns `now` and the JavaScript code that calls it and logs the value.)

Comment: @smarx, done please check it out.

Comment: Have you tried a much simpler test like `function getNow() public returns (uint256) { return now; }`? Assuming that returns the expected value, build up from there to see how your code is different from that.

Comment: (Also, where's the definition of `Document`? From the portion of the code you shared, I can't tell which field `now` is going into.)

Comment: the  `now` value goes into a uint field. and yes this did work before on an other project with web3 0.x version but, i mean returning correct `now` value.

Comment: Something's wrong with your code. You don't know what it is. Usually, that means you're making an assumption about the code that is incorrect. Just telling me that it goes "into a uint field" (aside from not telling me _which_ field) does me no good, because you could simply be wrong about that. I don't know why you're so reluctant to share your code when you're asking for help with it.

Comment: @smarx i shared the `struct Document` code. i really shared all the code that deals with that `now` value.

Comment: Did you try the simple function I suggested? Also what library are you using? Truffle? web3.js? What version?

Comment: I see your question says web3.js 1.0. What exact version? What is `deployed` doing?

Comment: it's web3js 1.0 beta 30 and `deployed` is from truffle, i use it mainly to get the deployed contract address. then i use that address with the web3 1.0 contract instance. I am using web3 1.0 because truffle uses web3 0.x version and that is not good when working with Quorum which i am using in here.

Comment: See if my answer helps. In the future, please tag your questions with Quorum if that's what you're using. (I added the tag to this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be running into a difference between Quorum and Ethereum. From https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/190:

> The reason the number is so large is that because it's in nanoseconds, not seconds, since epoch. With raft-based consensus we can produce far more than one block per second, which vanilla Ethereum implicitly disallows: the default timestamp resolution is in seconds, and every block must have a timestamp greater than its parent.

Comment: i should have thought about this, and marked my question with quorum too. thanks